# How do I use the HexoJS css helper from a nunjucks template?

Tags: nunjucks, hexo

I get the error:

```
Unhandled rejection Template render error: (unknown path) [Line 9, Column 6]
  unknown block tag: css
    at Object.exports.withPrettyErrors (/Users/me/hexo-site/node_modules/hexo-renderer-nunjucks/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:35:17)
```

My themes/theme-name/layout/layout.nunjucks file has this code:

```
<title>Site title</title>
{% css "css/style.css" %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunjucks does not have a `css` tag, and it doesn't look like `hexo-renderer-nunjucks` implements one either.

You can implement it yourself, but it looks easier to just use a filter:

```
env.addFilter('css', function(str) {
    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + str + '"></link"'
})
```

and use `{{"css/style.css"|css}}` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This makes it seem like EJS is the only viable template system for HexoJS, which is a bit disappointing.